# How I can determine if a method is implemented in a class in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have two classes(e.g. BusyMan and NotBusyMan), BusyMan want to watch a film,but he don't have time to get ticket,NotBusyMan can help him.
BusyMan has a property named delegate

```
@property(nonatomic) id<BusyManDelegate> delegate;
```

and NotBusyMan is a delegate of BusyMan

```
busyMan.delegate = notBusyMan;
```

also

```
@interface NotBusyMan : NSObject <BusyManDelegate>
```

and suppose there's a method declared in protocol BusyManDelegate

```
@protocol BusyManDelegate<NSObject>

@optional
- (BOOL)buyTicketForMe;
@end
```

it retures YES when NotBusyMan bought a ticket for BusyMan.
so BusyMan can ask NotBusyMan like this

```
BOOL result = [self.delegate buyTicketForMe];
if (result) {//I may watch the film now

}else{//Oh No

}
```

but buyTicketForMe is optional,so what if NotBusyMan didn't implement the method? we all know the result: an exception ,"unrecognized selector sent to instance...",may raise.
So, I want to add condition before delegate call the method ,

```
if (my delegate implemented the method,and it won't raise an excetion) {
   BOOL result = [self.delegate buyTicketForMe];
    if (result) {//I may watch the film now

    }else{//Oh No

    }
}
```

How can I write the condition part.

By the way,`responseToSelector:` won't help, it retures YES as soon as the receiver declared the SEL,implement thing will be ignored.

Comment: `respondsToSelector:` does not check declarations. It checks implementation. If it doesnt work for you, you have an error somewhere.

Comment: And this is why you should try code before posting a question to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to check `respondsToSelector` with particular object.

```
// *** Check method is implemented or not ***
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buyTicketForMe)]) {
    // *** Invoke method ***
    [self.delegate  performSelector:@selector(buyTicketForMe) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: @daredevil more complicated, hiding whats going on. Definitely worse code.